# What would happen to the wires if a lightning struck them?

Tags: wiring, lightning

I've got a link to this video of a lightning striking wiring between two houses in a city: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLPFeW40Xrc

I wonder if the wires were melted by the current (as commenters on various websites claim) or if it was just some effect that caused glowing orange particles to appear around those wires.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question fits the site. If you know a better SE site for it, please comment. Also, tags could probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Melted wire is entirely possible. You'd have to see more detail to be sure. Energy involved is liable to be vastly in excess of what is needed for melting.

Answer (score 2):

2 years ago a lightning stuck on our TV antenna. The 2 meters of coaxial cable from antennas to the amplifiers and splitters/mixers simply... disappeared! Devices under the roof almost melted, and luckily a 4 way splitter inside the house failed, saving TVs and DVRs from a bad destiny

Comment: I assume you weren't there at the event to see any bright particles around the wires?